# Formatting month and year using NSDateFormatter returns invalid date

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have set the locale and timezone but when I format the date, I always get invalid date. The month is always December and year is one less that the specified year. In my case I dont need the day component.

I checked other similar post but it didn't solved the problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
dateFormatter.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]; 
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM YYYY"];
NSDate *formattedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Sep 2013"];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:formattedDate]);
[dateFormatter release]; dateFormatter = nil;
```

**OUTPUT: Date: Dec 2012**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"YYYY" format is used for "Week of Year" based calendars. Use "yyyy" format specifier instead:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"];
```

Comment: @Vignesh, thanks for the link. Probably some format specifiers do not make sense for "Week of Year" calendar and that results in different results

Comment: Thanks @Vlad and Vignesh for your answers.

Comment: But this doesn't take in account the locale. Any idea how we can achieve the same in the user's locale?

Comment: @user1366265 You need to set the locale first, then set the date format. Otherwise locale will treat the format in weird and wonderful ways! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add something to the great answer by Vladimir. If you do this before setting your locale, it seems that the date formatting goes crazy. What I had to do was to set the locale before setting the new format, and then use the `setDateFormat` to change the format based on the locale used.So something like this would do:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];//I wanted to set the locale to wherever user is using my app in
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM YYYY"];
NSDate *now = [NSDate Date];
NSString *fancyLookingDate = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Comment: I think `[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];` and `[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];` are redundant in your code. If you use `setDateFormat`, the previous call to set date style and time style will be ignored.

Comment: @YuchenZhong didn't know that, thought date and time are formatted separately. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @YuchenZhong Just edited my answer to reflect your comment.